# Use the contact's page header on all pages (for mobiles)

Tags: php, mobile, header, osclass

How can I use the header (seach & category section) found on the contact page for the mobile version on all my pages? 
(pls see image attached)

I've tried replacing this code in the header.php file

```
<?php osc_current_web_theme_path('common/head.php') ; ?>
```

with

```
<?php osc_current_web_theme_path('header.php'); ?>
```

I've also tried a bunch of other things with no luck. Any idea how this could be achieved?

EDIT 1 - Removed the image as I can't add more than 2 links.

EDIT 2 - Below is the code in my contact.php file whose header section I am trying to replicate on all other pages

https://jpst.it/Vd7H

And below is the code in my header.php file

https://jpst.it/Vd89

Both contact.php and header.php files are in the same directory
I hope this will be enough

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you change:

```
<?php osc_current_web_theme_path('header.php'); ?>
```

to:

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
```

Also, are you sure the file you're calling exists in the same directory you're calling it from? What is your file structure?

Edit: I notice you've said you've put a reference to the header.php file **in** the header.php file - why are you referencing a file from itself? I'd need a sample of all the code to work out exactly what's going on, are you able to edit your question to clarify?

Comment: Hi Hayden - I've edited my original post to show the code in my contact.php page whose header section I am trying to replicate on all my other pages, as well as the code in my header.php file (which controls how the header section of all pages except contact.php look).

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, all I had to do was comment out the following line of code in the header.php file

```
<?php if( osc_is_static_page() || osc_is_contact_page() ){  ?>
```